# Append row1 data to row 2

Tags: excel, append, excel-formula

I need to append data of the alternate row like D1+D2 into Excel.

Please tell me how can I do that?

I have for example:

```
D1 = medical
D2 = Equipment
```

and I need:

```
D1 = medical Equipment
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put a formula in `D1` while also retaining `D1` as the source of the text for that formula. You mention alternate rows, so presumably you want `D3` with `D4` etc. Hence I'd suggest:

`=D1&" "&D2` in Row1 of some other unused column,

then copy that down as far as required,

copy that other column and paste special / values over the top of ColumnD,

tidy up by deleting the 'spare' column,

and delete contents of cells in ColumnD of even row number.

`&` strings together the text (concatenates) but to insert a space as well you must separate it with double inverted commas at each end.

Comment: thanks but i have number of row which i need to append. how to do for all the rows

Comment: it is giving the same value for the all rows. is there any function of macro which can help me

Comment: yes i have the long list of data which i extract from a pdf. now some data is coming like half in first row and half in 2 one. now i want to combine those row of data into first one and delete the second row. i am thinking that a good VB script can do a good job but i never done VB programmig so i am looking for a help. i not found a good script which can help me

Comment: but if you can help me with basic script which can add all data from odd to even and delete even row i will be thank full to you. rest i will try thnks

Comment: well thanks you for all this. really helpful but if u can help me any link of sript like i am looking for that will be really great.

Answer (score -1):

Insert a new column D. (moving old columns to the right)
Enter this formula in D1:

```
 =E1 & " " & F1
```

If you are trying to combine the data from the two columns, the & symbol will let you do that. However, the formula can't be in either of the two columns you are trying to combine which is why I reccomended inserting a column.

If you, for some reason, can't insert this formula into a column and must work only inside of the original two columns let us know and we can post VBA code that can assist. However, it sounds like the formula approach will be the simplest solution.

Comment: thanks but i have number of row which i need to append. how to do for all the rows